# How to pass arbitrary `json` data from python to bokeh using `CustomJS`

Tags: python, bokeh

I am working on a bokeh visualisation, one requirement is that it runs without a server, as such I am using `CustomJS` to implement interactivity on the client side using javascript. Passing `ColumnDataSource`s to `CustomJS` works fine to update plots interactively.

What I cannot do however, is just embed some arbitrary `json` data into the output html. See the self contained example below:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div, Button
from bokeh.plotting import show

data_for_client = {
    "x": 3,
    "y": {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": {"some_bar": "doge", "other bar": "much json"}
    },
    "z": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
}

callback = CustomJS(args={"data_for_client": data_for_client}, code="""
    console.log(data_for_client);
""")

content = widgetbox(
    Button(label="click here", callback=callback),
    Div(text="some complicated interactive stuff based on json content here")
)

output_file("issue.html")
show(content)
```

In my case, the `data_for_client` is a complicated deeply nested `json`, different parts of this `json` are used depending on user interaction with some widgets.

I do not need to make any modifications to the `json` data based on user interaction,  or attach any listeners or anything special. I just need the content of the json value to be available in the `CustomJS` callback.

For simple column data, I can wrap my data in a `ColumnDataSource` and pass that as an arg to `CustomJS`, however I do not find anything similar for plain `json` data. The code above fails with message:

```
ValueError: expected an element of Dict(String, Instance(Model)), got {'data_for_client': {'x': 3, 'y': {'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': {'some_bar': 'doge', 'other bar': 'much json'}}, 'z': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the first `data_for_client` to `"data_for_client"` in the related line, because otherwise you cannot use a dictionary ({...}) as a dictionary-key:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div, Button
from bokeh.plotting import show

data_for_client = {
    "x": 3,
    "y": {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3],
        "bar": {"some_bar": "doge", "other bar": "much json"}
    },
    "z": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
}

# Here is the change:
callback = CustomJS(args={"data_for_client": data_for_client}, code="""
    console.log(data_for_client); 
""")

content = widgetbox(
    Button(label="click here", callback=callback),
    Div(text="some complicated interactive stuff based on json content here")
)

output_file("issue.html")
show(content)
```

Comment: Ok, facepalm on my part. But this doesn't solve the problem, I edited the question in this regard.

Comment: I suppose there is something like Ajax/Json-Datasource

Comment: The Ajax data source exists and is meant for sending data from a web server as far as I know. I haven't found any json source in the docs.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer I am sorry but I am not used to bokeh and can't help you then

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it as a string, I would expect that there is stuff in javascript to read json data from a json string, I know this exists in python at least.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div, Button
import json

data_for_client = {
    "x": [3],
    "y": {
            "foo": [1, 2, 3],
            "bar": {"some_bar": "doge", "other bar": "much json"}
        },
    "z": [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
}

json_string = json.dumps(data_for_client)

DumButton = Button(label=json_string)

# Here is the change:
callback = CustomJS(args={"db":DumButton}, code="""
    console.log(db.label);
    var test=JSON.parse(db.label);
    console.log(test);
    for(key in test){console.log(test[key])}
    """)

content = widgetbox(
    Button(label="click here", callback=callback),
)

show(content)
```

Comment: While this technically works, it is far from ideal if you have a large json, since you have to parse the json (`JSON.parse()`in javascript) every time the `callback` is called. I have tried a similar solution as yours by passing the entire json as a string in a single cell of a `ColumnDataSource`, but there was a noticeable delay in user interaction.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer I edited my answer with code that works. using json.dumps on the python side and json.parseo n the JS side. I don't know if there is any way to make it faster. Would saving the json in a file on python and then read it from the customJS be faster? I don't know of a clean bokeh built-in way to pass nested dictonaries. You could map it to a list of lists and use a ColumnDataSource

Comment: The problem is the call to  `JSON.parse` in the line `var test=JSON.parse(db.label);`. This is re-evaluated every time the `callback` is called (i.e. every time you click the `click here` button in this example). Whereas for a `ColumnDataSource` the data gets parsed only once upon loading the document in your browser. You might be right that there is currently no other way. Yet this feature seems so simple that it should be there.

Comment: @SamDeMeyer If you don't need to modify your dictionary between the callback calls, you could have an initial callback do the same thing and put the json in a global scope variable, then it could be accessed directly from any CustomJS.I showed on this issue how you can add arbitrary js on a document https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6948 ; here it is for custom css but you can do the same for a custom script div

Comment: Ok I read the thread on github, and that combined with passing the json as a string seem like it would solve the issue indeed. It's rather clumsy/hacky, so I don't really like it. But I'll give you an upvote for your trouble. Thx :)

Comment: Yes it's very hacky. You could do it in a cleaner way by first writing the html document and then editing it with any custom script. In any case it is more work than one would expect for just passing a dictionary.